# Meaning of DBPedia SPARQL query that identifies concepts?

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

I don't understand the output generated by the following SPARQL query:

```sql
select distinct ?Concept
where {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Blink-182> a ?Concept
}
LIMIT 100
```

Can someone please explain me what does "concepts" mean in DBPedia, and what is the meaning of the result of this query?  Does it has any connection with **rdf:type**?

Comment: Using the keyword "a" is shorthand for writing rdf:type.

Comment: @AndyS Does rdf:type is a predicate in a triple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does it has any connection with `rdf:type`?

Yes - in SPARQL, `a` in a triple pattern is a shortcut for `rdf:type`, or, more precisely, `<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>`.

Therefore, the above query returns 100 IRIs that are used as the object in triples whose predicate is `rdf:type` - so to speak, 100 "types", or "concepts".

---

The query in your question is

```
select distinct ?Concept
where {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Blink-182> a ?Concept
}
LIMIT 100
```

This returns all types of `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Blink-182>`, i.e. all IRIs linked to `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Blink-182>` with the `rdf:type` property in the current DBpedia dataset. Concretely, these are:

- `<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing>`
- `<http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owl#Agent>`
- `<http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owl#SocialPerson>`
- `<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q215380>`
- `<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q43229>`
- `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent>`
- `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Band>`
- `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Group>`
- `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Organisation>`
- `<http://schema.org/MusicGroup>`
- `<http://schema.org/Organization>`
- `<http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/Band_MusicGroup>`
- `<http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/Organization>`

Taking the first two results as an example, this means that somewhere in the DBpedia dataset, the triples

```
S: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Blink-182>
P: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>
O: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing>
```

and

```
S: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Blink-182>
P: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>
O: <http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owl#Agent>
```

exist. Ditto for the other resulting IRIs.

Comment: Could you please provide me an example :)

Comment: if subject == Twilight.. and the predicate is rdf:type.. the concepts would be movie, love story. is it?

Comment: @Volka: An example of what? It seems you can successfully run the query, so you are getting plenty of examples of types that the indicated resource belongs to.

Comment: @ORMapper I want to understand clearly what those results are. Your answer is really helpful. But if you can tell it in a more simpler way, that will be really great :)

Comment: @Volka: I have added what I hope serves as an example.